# Excel ODBC Temp Tables not Working When Using Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, odbc, temp-tables

I am trying to run a query that includes a temp table and a parameter. These two things seem to not play well together and I'm struggling to come up with a work-around that allows me to use both of these. When I convert the query to not use the temp table it works, and conversely if I hard-code the parameter it works. My question is essentially: is there a way to be able to use temp tables and parameters together in Excel ODBC?

Here's the query I am running

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Department
FROM Reference.Department
WHERE OpeningDate < ?

SELECT * 
FROM #Department
```

I would expect to be able to map the parameter and run the query, but it returns the following error:

[Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXTGR.png)

Comment: Aside.. SQL Server Native Client 11.0 has not received any feature updates since SQL Server 2012, is not compatible with new protocol features in SQL Server 2014 and later, and Microsoft has **finally** stopped distributing it as of SQL Server 2022. It should not be used in new applications and existing applications should be migrated away from it to ODBC Driver 17/18 for SQL Server.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75903119/edit) your question to show how exactly you're calling this from Excel. If you're calling them in the same ADODB.Command, for example, then `#Department` doesn't exist yet for the select statement to pass syntax validation. Have you tried keeping the same ADODB.Connection object but running the two statements via separate ADBOB.Commands?